# Doubles rounding again

Tags: c++, double, rounding, c++98

In my program there are some precisions (some positive integer, in the most cases it supposed to be of the form [image: x*10^n]) for some doubles, so that `double * precision` should become an integer.

But as we all know floating point numbers are inaccurate, so, for example `1.3029515` could be saved as `1.3029514999999998...`, and in my program I need to write such floating point number to a file, but I want this `1.3029515` to be written instead of something like `1.3029514999999998...`.

Previously only precision of form [image: 10^n, 0<=n<=8] was used in my program, and I've reached the wanted result with a piece of code like below:

```
// I have a function for doubles equality check
inline bool sameDoubles(const double& lhs, const double& rhs, const double& epsilon) {
    return fabs(lhs - rhs) < epsilon;
}

inline void roundDownDouble(double& value, const unsigned int& numberOfDigitsInFraction = 6) {
    assert(numberOfDigitsInFraction <= 9);
    double factor = pow(10.0, numberOfDigitsInFraction);
    double oldValue = value;
    value = (((int)(value * factor)) / factor);
    // when, for example, 1.45 is stored as 1.4499999999..., we can get wrong value, so, need to do the check below
    double diff = pow(10.0, 0.0 - numberOfDigitsInFraction);
    if(sameDoubles(diff, fabs(oldValue - value), 1e-9)) {
        value += diff;
    }
};
```

But now, I can't reach wanted results with the same technique, I've tried with a function below, but have not succeeded:

```
// calculates logarithm of number with given base
double inline logNbase(double number, double base) {
    return log(number)/log(base);
}

// sameDoubles function is the same as in above case

inline void roundDownDouble(double& value, unsigned int precision = 1e+6) {
    if(sameDoubles(value, 0.0)) { value = 0; return; }
    double oldValue = value;
    value = ((long int)(value * precision) / (double)precision);
    // when, for example, 1.45 is stored as 1.4499999999..., we can get wrong value, so, need to do the check below
    int pwr = (int)(logNbase((double)precision, 10.0));
    long int coeff = precision / pow(10, pwr);
    double diff = coeff * pow(10, -pwr);
    if(sameDoubles(diff, fabs(oldValue - value),  diff / 10.0)) {
        if(value > 0.0) {
            value += diff;
        } else {
            value -= diff;
        }
    }
}
```

For `1.3029515` value and `precision = 2000000` this function returns incorrect `1.302951` value (expression `(long int)(value * precision)` becomes equal to `2605902` instead of `2605903`).

How can I fix this? Or maybe there is a some smart way to make this rounding happen correctly?

Comment: `expression (long int)(value * precision) becomes equal to 2605902 instead of 2605903`  [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/WQCPD69262)

Comment: Floating point numbers are *always* inaccurate, unless by some happy coincidence they can be written as a sum of powers of 2.  Like 0.5 or 0.025, but never 0.1.  Regenerating the number yourself does not change that, it makes it worse because you add calculation error.  If you want to expose happy round numbers then you have to write *strings*.

Comment: Floating point numbers aren't inaccurate. **Conversions** from character representations to floating-point values are often inaccurate; there are far more values that can be represented as character sequences than there are floating-point values. But, of course, there are also far more real numbers than there are text representations of real numbers, so if you like saying that floating-point representations are inaccurate, you can just as well say that text representations of numbers are inaccurate.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I can't reproduce it on a small test case also, actually that situation is reached in my large program, where I'm reading doubles from a file and doing a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your rounding the hard way. Do it the easy way instead:

```
double rounding = 0.5;
if (value < 0.0) rounding = -0.5;
value = ((long int)(value * precision + rounding) / (double)precision);
```

Now there's no need for the rest of the code.

Comment: I've tested [it](http://rextester.com/XHWPQK56783), and didn't get expected results.

Comment: But seems your suggestion with the rest of the code works fine.